# Facebook pixel causes strange text behaviour

Tags: facebook, pixel

Whenever I add the following code to a page of my website (https://traineeshipondernemen.nl/blog), some special characters start to misbehave. Ik have added two screen shots below to illustrate the problem.
The website is build with Bootstrap (4.3.1). Only html, css and Javascript.

Strange enough, the problem only occurs when I upload the file to the servers. When I run the site on my computer (local) everything looks fine.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '376622943264914'); 
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" 
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=376622943264914&ev=PageView
    &noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
```

[Page without Facebook Pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4un8Q.jpg)

[Page with Facebook Pixel - textual changes are highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvX6p.jpg)

Comment: Some sort of problem with character encoding, characters in UTF-8 getting interpreted as something else. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Ftraineeshipondernemen.nl%2Fblog lists _“The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252”_ as first error. You have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in there, but it comes after the tracking pixel codes - try and put it before, and see if that changes things.

Comment: This does solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. Thanks CBroe!

Some sort of problem with character encoding, characters in UTF-8 getting interpreted as something else. validator.w3.org/nu/… lists “The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252” as first error. You have  in there, but it comes after the tracking pixel codes - try and put it before, and see if that changes things.